# Fiber NIC on ubuntu server 18.04 error <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000

Tags: networking, server, 18.04

Fresh ubuntu server install and Unable to get network function from Fiber card - the main board's local ethernet NICs work fine though -

`Intel 10 gig fiber card`

### `product: 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection`

`~$ lshw -C network`

```
*-network:0
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
   logical name: enp10s0f0
   version: 01
   serial: 00:1b:21:82:c9:00
   capacity: 10Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical fibre 10000bt-fd
   configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=ixgbe driverversion=5.1.0-k firmware=0x18f10001 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
   resources: irq:16 memory:f8e80000-f8efffff ioport:c880(size=32) memory:f8e7c000-f8e7ffff memory:c0000000-c00fffff memory:c0100000-c01fffff
*-network:1 UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.1
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f8f80000-f8ffffff ioport:cc00(size=32) memory:f8f7c000-f8f7ffff memory:c0200000-c02fffff memory:c0300000-c03fffff`
```

---

`~$ ip a`

```
4: enp10s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1b:21:82:c9:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`
```

any idea's why this is happening?

---

### Requested data from forum contributors :D > thank you!

`~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3`

```
 04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:7666]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:7666]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
--
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection [8086:10fb] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Server Adapter X520-2 [8086:0003]
    Kernel driver in use: ixgbe
    Kernel modules: ixgbe
0a:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection [8086:10fb] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Server Adapter X520-2 [8086:0003]
    Kernel modules: ixgbe
0c:00.0 IDE interface [0101]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Device [1b4b:91a3] (rev 11)
--
0d:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1033:0194] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1462:7666]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
ff:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-Core Registers [8086:2c41] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon 5500/Core i7 QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-Core Registers [8086:8086]
```

---

`~$ dmesg | grep -e ixgbe -e enp`

```
[   13.645070] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: renamed from eth1
[   13.792859] ixgbe: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit PCI Express Network Driver - version 5.1.0-k
[   13.843330] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: renamed from eth0
[   14.044454] ixgbe: Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Intel Corporation.
[   15.328939] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: Multiqueue Enabled: Rx Queue count = 8, Tx Queue count = 8 XDP Queue count = 0
[   15.329073] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: PCI Express bandwidth of 16GT/s available
[   15.329076] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: (Speed:5.0GT/s, Width: x4, Encoding Loss:20%)
[   15.329078] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: This is not sufficient for optimal performance of this card.
[   15.329082] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: For optimal performance, at least 20GT/s of bandwidth is required.
[   15.329085] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: A slot with more lanes and/or higher speed is suggested.
[   15.329171] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: MAC: 2, PHY: 1, PBA No: E68785-003
[   15.329174] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: 00:1b:21:82:c9:00
[   15.330409] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit Network Connection
[   15.349286] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.1: failed to load because an unsupported SFP+ or QSFP module type was detected.
[   15.349291] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.1: Reload the driver after installing a supported module.
[   15.350364] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0 enp10s0f0: renamed from eth0
[   18.138949] ixgbe 0000:0a:00.0: registered PHC device on enp10s0f0
[   18.244897] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp10s0f0: link is not ready
[   18.313386] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: link down
[   18.313462] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp5s0: link is not ready
[   20.676505] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: link up
[   20.676515] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp5s0: link becomes ready
```

---

`~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

```
    # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
    enp10s0f0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
      nameservers:
          addresses:
                 [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

---

`~$ ip addr show`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 6c:62:6d:95:be:29 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.113.10.147/16 brd 10.113.255.255 scope global dynamic enp5s0
   valid_lft 689674sec preferred_lft 689674sec
inet6 fe80::6e62:6dff:fe95:be29/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 6c:62:6d:95:be:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp10s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1b:21:82:c9:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:fff `
```

---

~$ dmesg | grep -e ixgbe -e enp

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MdFvNysz8V/

Comment: *Unclaimed* indicates that there is no suitable driver yet. Let's find out which one it needs. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @ chili555 thank you! i've just made the edits :D

Comment: Weird. Now it shows a driver ixgbe. Let's have a look at: `dmesg | grep -e ixgbe -e enp` And also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` As the output may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be a multi-part answer as there are at least two faults that need attention. In order to fix the second, we need information gathered from fixing the first. I will subsequently edit this answer to give a further fix.

We see this in the log:

> ixgbe 0000:0a:00.1: failed to load because an unsupported SFP+ or QSFP module type was
>   detected.

Let's see if a driver parameter helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "options ixgbe allow_unsupported_sfp=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ixgbe.conf
exit
```

Reboot and show us:

```
ip addr show
```

We hope we see that the second interface appears now.

Comment: May we see a new: `dmesg | grep -e ixgbe -e enp` As your edits above are getting very long and it will soon be difficult to separate the old from the new, please post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: most recent ~$ dmesg | grep -e ixgbe -e enp  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MdFvNysz8V/

Comment: Please change the parameter. I wonder if =1 is correct instead of =Y. Simply repeat the sequence in my answer and reboot. Then run: `dmesg | grep ixgbe` and tell me if the quoted error above remains or has disappeared.

Comment: `~$ dmesg | grep ixgbe` results after change to Y https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KwJwRbdDnJ/

Comment: I asked that you change it to =1. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: no sweat but =1 was the original? 'echo `options ixgbe allow_unsupported_sfp=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ixgbe.conf` ill run these again then ?

Comment: @chilli555 results after changing to 1 https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BBk8QWWN5j/

Comment: @chilli555 we're up! suddenly the second nic on the Fiber card showed up so i moved the cable to is and walla. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour If you also need help setting up netplan, post here and we'll continue.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution that worked for my case. I'm using a Dell R730 Chassis with the intel x520 2 10G SFP+/2 1GBE NIC.

I'm not seeing the `eno1` device after installing Ubuntu 18.04.3

https://route1.ph/2019/09/27/stretch-ixgbe-driver-allow-unsupported-sfp-modules-on-intel-x520-cards/

```
echo "options ixgbe allow_unsupported_sfp=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/ixgbe.conf
depmod -a
update-initramfs -u -k `uname -r`
```

I had to reboot, as `netplan` apply did not bring up the interface `eno1`. After the reboot completed, interface shows up and I have connection.